# iOS - Interface Builder - Autolayout two labels

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

Not sure how to use autolayout on the two highest labels in the second prototype cell here:

[image]

We'll call the labels LABELX and LABELY.

Basically LABELX (selected) is left-aligned 10 pts from the UIImageView to its left, and LABELY (floating to the right) is 0 pts to the right from its superview.  Basically all I need is for LABELX to end before it overlaps LABELY, in the case that the former is super long.

I tried adding a constraint to LABELX of trailing space to LABELY, and altered the hugging priority of one or the other to 250 but it just produces some weird results.

Comment: You want to change the content compression resistance of labelx to be lower than labely, not the hugging priority.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dan's comment I arrived at the solution by setting BOTH the horizontal content compression resistance of LABELX and its horizontal content hugging priority to be lower than those of LABELY.